# spring mvc The prefix "ctx" for element "ctx:annotation-config" is not bound

Tags: xml, spring

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
    <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.wipro"></ctx:component-scan>

</beans>
```

Iam getting error in ctx:annotation-config line as The prefix "ctx" for element "ctx:annotation-config" is not bound.I am beginner please help me out.

Comment: user `context:annotation-config` instead of `ctx:annotation-config`

Answer (score 2):

Please add below line

```
xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
```

Answer (score 1):

As i can see in your XML configuration for the context is 
 ***xmlns:context***="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

So you should use context:annotation-config.